# scaling without changing the position of THREE.Line

Tags: three.js

I have line which is drawn between two vertices and using LineBasicMaterial. What I want to achieve is to increase the length of this line. I used

```
line.scale.z += 0.1;
```

on the object scaling it according to the direction in which it is drawn. This works but also messes up the position co-ordinates of the Line. So I had to update the position everytime with an offset on the scale change. Is there an easier way to increase the length? I'm a beginner in threejs, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is correct, however, usually the pattern is to scale the x-, y-, and z-components equally, like so:

```
line.scale.set( s, s, s );
```

You may then have to change the line's `position`.

An alternative is to modify the line's vertices directly, and then to set:

```
line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

three.js r.58

Comment: Merci Beaucoup. I just didnt want to update it manually. Alright.